# Second Functions program. Some inquiries

Tags: python

My book requires me to *Make another program using functions*, the catch is that I need to make it a little bit more complex this time, so instead of going for a simple addition I try to solve a very simple physics problem with values given to me by the user, using two functions (velocity and acceleration).

Heres the aim of the program (sampledoc)

> 1. Create a program that reads and prints this txt document
> 2. Introduces the Program and the name of the script
> 3. Uses a function to solve a problem, make the function more complex
>
>    - User gives distance (x) and time (t)
>    - Program calculates velocity and acceleration
> 4. Creates a new txt document and writtes the results in it
> 5. Prints the results of the problem directly from the new document.

And heres the code:

```
from sys import argv

script, textf = argv; sampledoc = open(textf)

def velocity (x, t):
    vel = (float(x)) / (float(t))
    return float(vel)

def acceleration (v, t):
    accel = (float(v)) / (float(t))
    return float(accel)

print "Hello my name is TAR or as my creator called me %s" % script; print sampledoc.read(); sampledoc.close()
print "Results will be printed on a new text document, thanks for your preference"

x = float(raw_input("Please introduce the Distance")); t = float(raw_input("Please introduce the time:... "))

vel = velocity(x, t)

accel = acceleration (velocity, t)

results = 'ResultsP.txt'
new_file = open(results, 'w')
new_file.write(str(vel)); new_file.write(str(accel))
new_file.close()

new_file.open(results, 'r')
print new_file.read()
new_file.close()
```

I know there's something wrong here, somewhere, but my brain isn't working right now, I suppose it has something to do with either the way I am trying to solve this or the ''floats'' I used in the function since I am getting this error:

```
  File "ex21Study.py", line 20, in <module>
    accel = acceleration (velocity, t)
  File "ex21Study.py", line 10, in acceleration
    accel = (float(v)) / (float(t)) 
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I googled this and found some answers on other similar issues that said something about converting my results to float or str, however, I tried both and with no fruitful results.

Comment: What is the *full traceback* of the error you see?

Comment: Style tip:  Do not use `;` in Python.  It makes your code hard to read and a real pain to adjust/maintain.  The only time it is acceptable is for quick snippets in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a *function* here:

```
accel = acceleration (velocity, t)
```

`velocity` is not a floating point value; it is a function object. You probably meant to use `vel` instead here, which you calculated on the preceding line:

```
vel = velocity(x, t)
accel = acceleration(vel, t)
```